# How to Create Custom ID Auto Increment in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

What should I do to create custom ID auto increment like "queue number-date-month" in codeigniter?

Ex: 
001-29-10, 
002-29-10, 
003-29-10, 
004-30-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set id's to auto-increment in your database tables where you created queue.
Take those id's and put the below function
inside Some of your controller

```
public function q()
{
        $id = "001"."-"; // you have to replace 001 with your id's from db
        $d = date('d-m') ;

        $customid = $id.$d;

        echo $customid; //results as 001-30-10
}
```